is the Moksha Krishna is offering Arjuna in the Bhagavad-Gita anything other than Advaitic realization?
As far as I know, Krisha in his own words in the Bhagavad-Gita never relates himself to the Vaishnavite pantheon or to the great deeds of Vishnu.  In the context of what he is teaching Arjuna, "Vasudeva" just means "indwelling spirit".  It is only Sanjaya and Arjuna who say he is Vishnu.  Whatever Arjuna saw in the Vishwarupa of Krishna - only Arjuna is the witness to that. When Krishna says "among the Adityas, I am Vishnu" it is just a "best of breed" statement.  he also says things like "among the letters, I am the letter 'a'".
he never offers Arjuna Vaikuntha or Goloka or any of the Vaishnavite higher abodes, which are supposed to be the final destination of realized Vaishnavites.
Is it only self-realization in the here-and-now that Krishna is offering Arjuna?

Don't you already quite have the answer you want? Seems more like an attempt to simply affirm existing beliefs.

Lord Krishna considers Advaitaic realization as only one possibility.
Jnana Yoga is praised.
Power of Divine Knowledge

Even if you happen to be the worst of sinners, you will surely go
across all sin by the raft of divine knowledge.

Gita 4.36

Just as a well-kindled fire reduces a heap of fire-wood to ashes, so
does the fire of divine knowledge reduces all sins to ashes.

Gita 4.37
Verily there is nothing so purifying as knowledge in this world. One who is perfect in Yoga discovers it in oneself in course of time.
Gita 4.38

A man of deep faith (Sraddha) obtains this divine knowledge, being
full of zeal and devotion for it and endowed with mastery of the
senses. Having obtained that knowledge, he is established in supreme
peace very soon.

Gita 4.39

Out of sheer compassion for them, residing within as their innermost
self, I destroy the darkness born of ignorance in them by the
brilliant lamp of wisdom.

Gita 10.11
Karma Yoga is praised.

Men like Janaka verily attained to perfection by work alone. You ought
to work for the good of the world (having their example in view).

Gita 3.20
Bhakti Yoga is lavishly praised.
Praise of devotion to the Lord

But the high souled ones, endowed with virtues characteristic of
Devas, understand Me to be the Immutable and the source of all beings,
and adore Me with a mind undistracted by anything else.

Gita 9.13

Strenuous and steadfast in their vows, these ever-integrated devotees
worship Me with devotion, always singing My glories and prostrating
before Me.

Gita 9.14

Thus, shall you be freed from the bonds of Karma bearing good and evil
fruits. With the heart firmly set on renunciation, you will attain
liberation and thereby come to Me.

Gita 9.28

To those who serve Me with delight and are ever steadfast in spiritual
communion, I bestow intuitive understanding by means of which they
come to me.

Gita 10.10
Sri Krishna acknowledges the three paths of Advaita, Vishistadvaita and dvaita.
Three classes of worshippers

Others, again, who offer wisdom sacrifice to Me, worship Me the
all-inclusive whole (All-formed) – as the One, as the Distinct, and as
the Immanent in all.

Gita 9.15
Difficulty of Jnana marga

Those who are devoted to the Imperishable (the Impersonal Absolute), -
who is the firm support of the world and is also undefinable,
unmanifested, transcendent, motionless, eternal and all-pervading –
even they reach Me alone, striving with their senses controlled, and
with the mind tranquillised and set on the welfare of all.

Gita 12.3-4

The obstacles facing those devoted to the Impersonal Absolute are far
greater; for the way of an unclear ideal is difficult for an embodied
being (the body-centered man) to understand or follow.

Gita 12.5
It seems to me that Lord Krishna accepts the realization of all three types of Vedanta and not just Advaita realization.

In Bhagavad Gita 9:15 it seems like only dvaita and Advaita are present

Except for "Vasudeva"(which just means "indwelling spirit" here, there is no evidence in his own words that the speaker of the Gita is from the Vishnuic pantheon.  He never says to worship the one with Shankha, Chakra and Gada wearing Pitambara.  The Gita's Bhakti is not Bhakti as we understand it now -offering flowers, incense and reciting prayers. @PradipGangopadhyay

@SK. //The Gita's Bhakti is not Bhakti as we understand it now -offering flowers, incense and reciting prayers.// Then how do you explain Gita 9.16

@SK This is what Gita says about rituals regarding Bhakti: Whoever makes an offering to Me with devotion, be it of leaf, flower, fruit or water – that devout offering made by a pure hearted man, I accept with joy.
Gita 9.26

The Gita isn't monolithic.  Just like Ramakrishna used to teach Bhakti to simple devotees, Kishna has put in these simple verses for lay folk.  I find the पत्रं पुष्पं फलं तोयं line jarring - compared to the lofty language in the rest of the Gita.  And it is NOT in the Bhakti-yoga chapter !!!!!!!!!!!!  @PradipGangopadhyay

The other answer addresses the main question. The focus of this answer is this statement -

As far as I know, Krisha in his own words in the Bhagavad-Gita never relates himself to the Vaishnavite pantheon or to the great deeds of Vishnu.

Below is the direct description of the Vishwaroopa by Arjuna in 11th chapter.

kirīṭinaṅ gadinaṅ cakriṇaṅ ca


tējōrāśiṅ sarvatōdīptimantam.


paśyāmi tvāṅ durnirīkṣyaṅ samantā-


ddīptānalārkadyutimapramēyam৷৷11.17৷৷


I see Thee with the diadem, the club and the discus, a mass of radiance shining everywhere, very hard to look at, blazing all round like burning fire and the sun, and immeasurable.

The club (gada) and chakra are standard weapons of Bhagavan Vishnu.
Also, when Arjuna requests Krishna to come back to original form, he says this -

kirīṭinaṅ gadinaṅ cakrahasta-


micchāmi tvāṅ draṣṭumahaṅ tathaiva.


tēnaiva rūpēṇa caturbhujēna


sahasrabāhō bhava viśvamūrtē৷৷11.46৷৷


I want to see You just as before, wearing a crown, wielding a mace, and holding a disc in hand. O You with thousand arms, O You of Cosmic form, appear with that very form with four hands.

Chaturbhuja, carrying chakra, gada are standard descriptions of Bhagavan Vishnu.
Hence, both the Viswarupa and normal forms of Bhagavan Krishna are associated with standard Vaishnava symbols.

do you know what "in his own words" means @estimator ?

@SK I think actions are stronger than words. By carrying the standard Vaishnava weapons, Bhagavan relates Himself to Vishnu

@SK he does call himself Vasudeva, but i see that you do not accept that as sufficient. Strictly  speaking, even Vishnu means one who is all pervading and using this logic any Vaishnava association can be denied.

@SK i also see that you talk of Shankha, Chakra, gada in one of your comments. So I hoped to address that aspect too.

what "Vaihnava weapons" do you think Krishna was carrying as Arjuna's charioteer? @estimator ?  Whatever Arjuna saw was only in his imagination.  If you notice - his behavior towards Krishna didn't change after he saw his Vishwarupa.

@SK I tried to provide an answer to the best of my abilities.
